# Change a h tag in an MySQL string column

Tags: mysql, function, replace, tags

I have a MySQL table with column where fields are strings beginning like this:

```
<h2>texttext</h2>texttexttext....

<h2>text2text2</h2>texttexte......
```

I would like to replace h2 to h1 tag for all fields in the column. I have tried using the REPLACE query like this one:

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET column = REPLACE(column, 'h2>', 'h1>')
```

But it did not work.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: That should have worked. What error did you get? (Of course, assuming you did actually ONLY match the `h2>` and not something else such as `tableh2>`)

Comment: Are you sure your content isn't HTML encoded? Like `h2&gt;` instead of `h2>`?

Answer (score 0):

Dump whole database to SQL file. Search replace in any text editor. Import back.